# Delete image after upload new one

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working with laravel 5.4 I have a form which I can upload my logo`image` and in update function I have this code:

```
//Save logo
         if ($request->hasFile('logo')) {
           $avatar = $request->file('logo');
           $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
           $location = public_path('avatars/logos/');
           $request->file('logo')->move($location, $filename);
           $oldFilename = $general_Settings->logo;

           $general_Settings->logo = $filename;
           Storage::delete($oldFilename);
         }

         $general_Settings->save();
```

for updating my image which is work but as you see I have `Storage::delete($oldFilename);` this part doesn't work and just keep the old image.

what do you think is issue of that?

Comment: Did you check file path is correct ?

Comment: yes, file will save in correct path, only will not delete the old one.

Comment: You need to give full path from public folder to delete image

Comment: how could i do that?

Comment: Simple, I have posted in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

The issue was `Filesystem.php` I made my local root set to `'root' => public_path('avatars/'),` and changed all my functions in my app because no way to save images in sub-folders and delete them just can save in sub-folders.

then my update function become like this:

```
 if ($request->hasFile('logo')) {
        $avatar = $request->file('logo');
        $filename = 'sitelogo' . '-' . time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location = public_path('avatars/');
        $request->file('logo')->move($location, $filename);


        $general_Settings->logo = $filename;
      }

      $general_Settings->save();
```

I hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Since, You have stored logo file name only not full path of file,

You need to give full path from public folder to delete image. Change delete line as:

```
if ($request->hasFile('logo')) {
       $avatar = $request->file('logo');
       $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
       $location = public_path('avatars/logos/');
       $request->file('logo')->move($location, $filename);

       $oldFilename = $general_Settings->logo;
       $file_path = "avatars/logos/".$oldFilename;

       $general_Settings->logo = $filename;
       Storage::delete($file_path);
     }

     $general_Settings->save();
```

This might work.

Comment: I have updated try once again, otherwise you may not have correct permission to storage folders

Comment: still old photo exist or maybe i put your code wrong would you please give me full code?

Comment: Try this one, may help you

Comment: no everything works just fine, only not delete old image.

Comment: have you checked permissions to the folder ?

Comment: no i didn't, i'm on windows (local) don't know how to check it!

Comment: In windows, I think there is no issue regarding permissions

Comment: Have you tried `dd($oldFilename)` If this is null then file delete fails

Comment: well on my dd will get this `"1496977400.jpg"` which is the name of old file.

Comment: So, now I don't know what's problem with your code. May other people here may provide you solution

Comment: Have you checked filesystem.php inside config folder ? You should have something like this:
`'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path(),
        ],`

Comment: yes that was my problem i already solved it but also cause all my app because i cannot save files in sub-folders so i had to change all my functions.